# can someone help, what to do when we have "value" and we don't know how composes the "value"?

Tags: c#

This is my code. I don't understand how to make a `value` that equal to 165. There is `int heightless` how can I enter the number or value in `height` and the `x` can adjust the number I put in `height`, but the value is still 165? `x` is a hint only not any code.

```
using the System;

namespace For_Learn_5
{
    Class program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Want to register as a police officer

            int age;
            int height;

            Console.Write("Enter your age: ");
            age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Enter your height: ");
            height = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            int Overage = age - 21;

            if(age >= 18 && age <=21 && height >= 165)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Congratulations you are accepted");
            }
            else if (age < 17 && height < 165)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry you don't qualify");
            }
            else if (height < 165)
            {
                int Overage02 = age - 21;
                int heightLess = height + x = 165;
            }
        
            else
            {
                Overage = age - 21;
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry your age is " + Overage + " years older");
            }
           



            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you want the variable `heightLess` to be set to a value equal to how much less than 165 the `height` variable is. You can do this with simple subtraction:

```cs
int heightLess = 165 - height;
```

Comment: nice, that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it right, you want *X* to be a different value depending on the *Height*, right?

You could use a *ternary* `if`.

```
int heightLess = (height < 165) ? height + x : height - x;
```

In this case the (height < 165) condition will be evaluated first and value assigned to heightless will depend on whether it`s `true` -> `?` or `false` -> `:`.

You could also create constants to avoid using literals:

```
private const int MINIMUM_HEIGHT = 165;
```

Then replace every time you use 165 by MINIMUM_HEIGHT. The same with MINIMUM_AGE and MAXIMUM_AGE.

If the user enters 17 for age, the output will be `"Sorry your age is " + Overage + " years older"` and it will show that the user is **-4** years old.